# Import database with SSDT programmatically

Tags: sql-server, database, deployment, sql-server-data-tools

I have a situation where I need to copy everything out of a database (except data) and deploy it to a new database. I am currently doing this by importing from the existing database into SSDT and then publish the project to the new database.

I want to know if there is a way I can do this programmatically. Ideally I would like to have a process in place where I can give the process the name of the database to copy from, the name of the database to copy to, and then the process  would just automatically carry out the import and export.

What might be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SSDT is powered by a library called the Data-Tier Application Framework (also known as DacFX).  DacFX is a public API that you can use to extract and publish dacpac files.  You can find a copy of DacFX in Program Files under Visual Studio or SQL Server in a directory something like this:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\130
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin

You can download the latest version of DacFX here: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51672

Note that when you install DacFX it's also necessary to install its dependencies, SqlSysClrTypes and SqlDom, which can be found in the System Requirements section of the above download page.

To use DacFX to extract and publish a dacpac file, you can use [SqlPackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx), like so:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe /a:extract /scs:"Data Source=YOURSERVER;Initial Catalog=YOURDB;Integrated Security=true" /tf:C:\temp\yourdb.dacpac`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe /a:publish /tcs:"Data Source=YOURSERVER;Initial Catalog=YOUROTHERDB;Integrated Security=true" /sf:C:\temp\yourdb.dacpac`

Alternately, you can use DacFX programmatically using the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac API, like so:
`using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DacServices ds = new DacServices("Data Source=YOURSERVER;Initial Catalog=YOURDB;Integrated Security=true");
        ds.Extract(@"C:\temp\yourdb.dacpac", "YOURDB", "AppName", new System.Version());
        using (DacPackage dp = DacPackage.Load(@"C:\temp\yourdb.dacpac"))
        {
            ds.Deploy(dp, "YOUROTHERDB");
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it programatically but I would say the easiest would be to buy a license for redgate sqlcompare and using the command line version of that.

Answer (score 0):

[Database Create Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcLLj.png)

[2]: Run this Script in code

I hope It Help

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wanting to this programmatically