# Deploy database using .dacpac file from .Net Core 2.0 application

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, dacpac

I'm trying to `migrate` my app from `net 4.6.1` to `netcore2.0` and some problems with  `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac` have been occurred. I'm deploying the database from a `.dacpac` file using `DacServices (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac 1.0.1)`, but this `package supports` only `net 4.6.1.` How can I deploy `.dacpac` file from `netcore` application?
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`.NET Core` support for `DacFx`](https://github.com/Microsoft/DACExtensions/issues/20) is planned, but not here yet and you can't do it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36484784/804385) in `.NET Core`. Now if add a `NuGet` package [`Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64/) restore will print you:

> Package 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64 140.3881.1' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'

For a while, you can use the command line utility [`SqlPackage.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx)

```
SqlPackage.exe 
  /Action:Publish 
  /SourceFile:C:/file.dacpac 
  /TargetConnectionString:[Connection string]
```

And you can run it programmatically:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
{
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\<Version>\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe",
    Arguments = "/Action:Publish /SourceFile:C:/file.dacpac /TargetConnectionString:[Connection string]"
};
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: is there still no way to deploy a dacpac (from .NET core) without calling the sqlpackage.exe?

Comment: @bytedev as I mentioned in answer keep an eye on https://github.com/Microsoft/DACExtensions/issues/20

Comment: I only asked cos your original answer is now 2.5 years old ;-)

Comment: As we can see at the moment `DacFx .NET Core Support #20` is still `Open`

Comment: I have incorporated the answer into my `post-build event command line` so that the database is automatically created.

Comment: This answer should be updated as the GA package supporting .NET Core is out already. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DACFx

Answer (score 5):

Good news as of Nov 15, 2018:

> ... the preview package which supports netcoreapp2.1 and net46:
>   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DACFx/150.4240.1-preview

Be mindful it's the Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx nuget package not the Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x86 nor Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64 packages and you need to enable pre-release mode in nuget.

Discussed in the same thread:

https://github.com/Microsoft/DACExtensions/issues/20#issuecomment-439222493

Next up, I need to find out if it works...

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx nuget package is now released for netstandard2.0:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx/

To publish a dacpac file to SQL Server LocalDB you can use:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac;

...

var dacpac  = DacPackage.Load(@"path\to.dacpac");
var dacpacService = new DacServices("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TargetDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
dacpacService.Publish(dacpac, "TargetDatabase", new PublishOptions());
```